# Change current component content depending on selected tab

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I have a component with v-tabs in it.
I am trying to change the content of a div which is outside of the tabs element depending on the selected tab, But i have no idea how to accomplish it. Its like i need to use v-router withing the component and give each tab different href.
I dont want the content to be withing v-tab-item. I want to use the tabs like a navbar

My code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<v-tabs v-model="tab" class="elevation-2" dark :centered="true" :grow="true">
    <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
    <v-tab v-for="i in tabs" :key="i" :href="`#tab-${i}`">{{ i }}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
 <div>
     <!-- Change selected component according to selected tab -->
    <ChildComponentOne/>
    <ChildComponentTwo/>
    <ChildComponentThree/>
 </div>


<script>
data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["ChildOne", "ChildTwo", "ChildThree"],
    };
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not give the tabs onclick handlers and then depending on which tab was clicked, you update the component?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something along the lines of a method.

Depending on what i returns you have to change some things, like the v-if. There is a lot of ways to do what you want, I have given you a very bread and butter answer to get you into the right direction.

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab" class="elevation-2" dark :centered="true" :grow="true">
    <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
    <v-tab v-for="i in tabs" :key="i" :href="`#tab-${i}`" @click="tabs(i)">{{ i }}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
 <div>
     <!-- Change selected component according to selected tab -->
   <div v-if="selectedTab === 1">
    <ChildComponentOne/>
   </div>
   <div v-if="selectedTab === 2">
    <ChildComponentTwo/>
   </div>
   <div v-if="selectedTab === 3">
    <ChildComponentThree/>
   </div>
 </div>


<script>
data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["ChildOne", "ChildTwo", "ChildThree"],
      selectedTab: null,
    };
  },
methods: {
    tabs(tab) {
      this.selectedTab = tab
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what i did when i saw @Geshode comment, It works fine. But is that the best way. Say every child component has large data which is passed as prop by the parent component which has to get it from the server, should i load all data at created event or load data when tab is selected?

Comment: Its best loading majority of the data on the parent, and only loading the extra required data on ur child. If you load everything on the child, your going to load all the data every time you swap through your tabs. This would also affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Id recommend keeping to the scope of the vuetify component. The documentation shows that you have three components you can use for this base tabs component. **tabs**, **tab** and **tab-item**

So you can do something like this with an list of Objects and dynamic components:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

```js
<v-tabs v-model="tab" class="elevation-2" dark :centered="true" :grow="true">
    <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
    <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="index" :href="`#tab-${index}`">{{ item.name }}</v-tab>

 <v-tab-item v-for="(item, i) in tabs" :key="index" :value="'tab-' + index">
     <Component :is="item.component"></Component>
 </v-tab-item>

</v-tabs>

<script>
// Import your childcomponents
data() {
    return {
    tabs: [
    { name: "ChildOne", component: "ChildComponentOne" },
    { name: "ChildTwo", component: "ChildComponentTwo" },
    { name: "ChildThree", component: "ChildComponentThree" },
    ],
  },
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

I haven't tested this code but i think you get the idea